# php xml eacute error

Tags: php, xml

please help me here.i got this error

```
<Name>secret CAKES &amp; CAF&Eacute;
imited</Name>
XML Parsing Error: undefined entity
Location: http://localhost/xml.php
```

in my php

```
htmlentities($row['companys'],ENT_QUOTES)
```

Answer (score 8):

`&Eacute;` is a valid HTML entity, but not a valid XML entity (unless you define it).

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) instead.

Make sure your XML document defines the correct charset, too.

Answer (score 5):

Your XML file is invalid, as `&Eacute;` isn't a default character entity for XML documents.

You should to replace it by `&#201;` or to correctly encode it.

Comment: @Ayrad, you're probably using a page charset unavailable in your machine; Try ISO-8859-1 and/or take a look into this HTML entity reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Answer (score 2):

É is an html entity, not an xml one therefore you can only use it html or xhtml documents, not xml documents.

There are only 5 entities defined for xml

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML

You should leave all other entities as unicode characters in your xml document then if you need to convert them to html entities, do it when you display the data from your xml rather than when you create your xml document (ie so that the é is converted after the xml is parsed)

Alternatively you could define the additional html entities in your xml document.  This comment on the php htmlentities page uses this method

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php#84327

Answer (score -1):

`htmlspecialchars($row['companys'],ENT_QUOTES)`

Comment: Welcome to SO :) By the way, if an answer is good for you, you should "check it" and make it the accepted answer instead of adding another answer to reply. StackOverflow is not like a forum. Thanks.